# Angular-UI select2 dynamically change tags attribute in options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-select2, angular-ui

Official example for Angular-ui select2 tags is:

```
myAppModule.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.list_of_string = ['tag1', 'tag2']
    $scope.select2Options = {
        'multiple': true,
        'simple_tags': true,
        'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4']  // Can be empty list.
    };
});
```

And I have this piece of code:

```
$scope.select2Options = {
                        'multiple': true,
                        'simple_tags': true,
                        'tags': $scope.categoryNames
                    };

$scope.$watch(function () { return adminCrudService.getCategoriesForUpdate(); }, function () {
                $scope.action = "edit";
                $scope.categoriesForUpdate = adminCrudService.getCategoriesForUpdate();
                if ($scope.categoriesForUpdate.length > null) {
                    $scope.categoryNames = [];
                    _.forEach($scope.categoriesForUpdate, function (item) {
                        $scope.categoryNames.push(item._backingStore.Name);
                    });

                }
            });
```

But this just doesn't work, when I click on Selcet2, I get *No matches found* and I've logged *$scope.categoryNames* inside $watch, and data is there (so that part works fine).

So my question is can *tags* be loaded dynamically, and if they can, how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I couldn't get it to work, so I've deiced to use Chosen instead, following this great tutorial: [link](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-chosen-plugin-awesome/) and I got result I wanted in no-time.

Answer (score 9):

I've recently encountered this issue when using the AngularUI Select2 project, and solved it by making the tags argument a function that returns the model. For example:

```
$scope.select2Options = {
  multiple: true,
  simple_tags: true,
  tags: function () {
    return $scope.categoryNames;
  }
};
```

Any updates to the `$scope.categoryNames` is reflected in the view because Select2 calls the `tags` function when opened and on every key press.

Hopefully this is useful for people wanting to use Select2 rather than Chosen.